# Is this good database design practice for document tracking?

Tags: database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many, coalesce, dense-rank

I'm trying to design a database for tracking documents. Every document can have multiple versions and every version has a number of properties associated with it. However, each version can be linked to multiple categories. The only shared property between versions is the document name.

My current design is

Documents Table:

- id (primary key)
- name

DocumentVersions Table

- id (primary key)
- document_id (foreign key)
- description
- revision_reason
- etc...
- timestamp

DocumentCategories Table

- id (primary key)
- name

DocumentVersionsDocumentCategories Table

- document_version_id
- document_category_id
- (together these make the primary key)

I was wondering if this structure looks okay? Also what would be the case for using a DocumentVersionsDocumentCategories join table vs just having a DocumentCategoriesTable with fields: id, document_version_id, name? And also would there be any reason to have a timestamp field on the Documents Table?

The api will need to be able to search, filter, and paginate on the documents, showing all the categories for each document, and the timestamp of the latest version. i.e returning an array of documents like:

```
[{ name: "first doc", categories: "first category, second category", timestamp: 01/01/2019 }, 
{ name: "second doc", categories: "second category", timestamp: "01/01/2020 }, 
{ name: "third doc", categories: "fourth category", timestamp: 01/01/2019 }]
```

I'm guessing I will need to join on all these tables and use dense rank, and coalesce as well?

Comment: At a quick glance, this is just a junction table design, with three tables, along with a fourth table to keep the document names normalized.  It seems reasonable to me, but your question is a bit too broad because it asks about so many things.

Comment: should i be splitting this into multiple questions maybe then? sorry, i just don't have much experience on a lot of this

Comment: After you asked if the schema were OK, that is probably a good stopping point for one question.  Even that would be a little bit too broad, but you might get an answer.

Comment: okay thank you! could i ask you specifically about the implementation of categories? i.e what would be the case for using a separate DocumentVersionsDocumentCategories join table vs just having the category name on the DocumentVersions table?

Comment: The issue is normalization, and the possible repetition of information unnecessarily.  If a given version could be related to more than one category, or vice-versa, then your second suggestion might result in information being repeated.

Comment: oh sorry... i meant DocumentCategories table. so i would just add another column version_id to that table. there would be many rows with repeated names but if i'm using the junction table instead, wouldn't i just have a lot of repeated category_ids instead?

Comment: am i right in thinking that in this specific case, it's not a big deal since categories only has 1 name field? i definitely understand that if the categories table stored more information on each category, then this duplication would be a major issue. and so in my case would it be ok to do without the junction table? i guess if i ever wanted to record more information about each category in the future, then i would an issue. am i understanding all the trade offs?

Comment: You dont want to have CategoryName on DocumentVersion table, because it is a fixed set of values that are presumably searchable. Not only would this mean repetition because every document about "Travel" includes the word for every version, but you are also open to typos in the word "Travle". My only question is whether the link should be between DocumentVersion and Category, or Document and Category. In your example the category may change version to version. Is that what you want?

Comment: thanks for the response! what if in the case categories weren't fixed (if they were implemented more like hashtags)? and yes the categories may change version to version. if they stayed the same then i definitely would have the link between document and category!